# Formatting number via java.text.DecimalFormat always returns error in SSJS

Tags: java, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am trying to format a number using `java.text.DecimalFormat` in SSJS but it returns an error. Here is my code snippet.

```
var df:java.text.DecimalFormat = new java.text.DecimalFormat("000");
df.format(50);
```

This returns an error of **`Ambiguity when calling format(long) and format(double)`**. So I tried to parse the number as double or long but still the same error.

```
df.format(java.lang.Long.parseLong("50"));     //Returns same error
df.format(java.lang.Double.parseDouble("50")); //Returns same error
```

I created a Java implementation of the above SSJS code and it works fine.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("000"); 
return df.format(50);
```

I have quite a few lines of SSJS code (of which the above snippet is part of) and creating a new Java class for two lines seems too much effort. Anyone knows why this doesn't work in SSJS?

Comment: Interesting, it seems to a bug in SSJS interpreter. When parameter is a number it just tries to find a method which accepts a number. When there are two of them it does not know which one to pick. I suggest opening a ticket with IBM to get this bug reported.

Comment: I wrote a little helper "class" a while back that might be of use:
http://dontpanic82.blogspot.no/2010/04/xpages-code-for-numberstring-conversion.html

Comment: @PanuHaaramo: How would I go about opening a ticket to this bug reported to IBM? I haven't raised any bug to IBM before.

Comment: @TommyValand: Thanks for the snippet! But now I am seriously considering creating a Java class for those two lines rather than hacking my way through it. :)

Comment: As W_K said this seems to be the way JavaScript is specified to work, not a bug. IBM support: https://www-947.ibm.com/support/servicerequest/Home.action?lnk=msdTS-srap-usen. You'll need to be registered as tecknical contact (or something) to be able to open PMRs'

Comment: But of course it would be nice if it would pick one of the methods that accepts a number!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Naveen: Have you tried below code, it worked for me without creating any java class :)

```
var df:java.text.DecimalFormat = new java.text.DecimalFormat("000");
var dblNum: java.lang.Double = new java.lang.Double(50);
return df.format(dblNum);
```

Thanks, please let me know your comments on this ;)

Comment: Thanks Prabhakar! Your trick worked. While I have already created a Java class it may be helpful to some one else. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

It does not work because SSJS cannot tell the difference between double and float (this is by design - javascript has only concept of number with 64 bit precision).

You can probably hack this with reflection:

```
var df:java.text.DecimalFormat = new java.text.DecimalFormat("000");
df.getClass().getMethod("format", Double.class).invoke(df, 50);
```

But I would rather create some custom java utils classes for this purpose. SSJS is awful for almost anything except for calling java.

Comment: I would create Java class rather than hacking my way through it. Thanks :)