# How to use BigDecimal in Xpages?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

I'm using stored numeric values in calculations and matching situations and javascript doubles are a big "NO-NO" when doing these kind of operations.

However I can't find a solution on how to use java BigDecimal in SSJS in Xpages.

Since one should construct a BigDecimal using a string I have tried different approaches i SSJS. Whatever test the result is the same, the call is ambiguous:

> *Ambiguity when calling new java.math.BigDecimal(long) and new
>   java.math.BigDecimal(int)*

1. How do I use a BigDecimal in my SSJS when values are stored in documents as Numbers?
2. How do I use BigDecimal with a string argument when values are stored in documents as Numbers?

**edit/amend:**
After accepting Svens answer I got a bit further and to my second question.

The value retrieved from the document is **451368** but it will be stored in variable as **451367.99999999994**

How do I recover from that when the user should match against original value?

Comment: Are you sure that *451368* is stored in the backend document? I can reproduce the issue when storing *451367.999999999* in the document.

Comment: Well at least when I view document properties from view.

Comment: The value in the view can be rounded from the column properties. Check the field in the document properties.

Comment: Yes I know but I don't look at the view column, I look at document properties from the view…

Comment: One more thing; if I retrieve the text value of the field then the value is correct however then I can't create a BigDecimal on that text string due to Locale issues…

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formatting number via java.text.DecimalFormat always returns error in SSJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087998/formatting-number-via-java-text-decimalformat-always-returns-error-in-ssjs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Java-Objects instead:

```
var value = new java.lang.Integer(1);
new java.math.BigDecimal(value);
```

Comment: `var test = new java.lang.Double(document1.getItemValueDouble("PaymentAmount"));
  
viewScope.BIG = java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(test);
`
My problem is that the value fetched is 351768 but after conversion it becomes 351767,99999994

Comment: The value is stored as a double in the back end, so your precision is limited by that. The main advantage of BigDecimal is to not lose any further precision when doing additional operations on the value. Have a look at the accepted answer here for more explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856136/java-inaccuracy-using-double